# Deshabilitar un Entry al estar marcada una opcion en un combobox Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Esta es mi interfaz, consiste en un **combobox** con tres opciones únicamente **(Elasticidad, masa, ∆x)**. Tres **entry** y un **botón**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que cuando tenga la opción "**Elasticidad**" del combobox marcada se desactive el segundo entry. Cuando tenga la opcion "**masa**" se desactive solo el primer entry y asi

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código que tienes hecho? De ese modo quien quiera ayudarte podrá probar modificaciones a tu código sin tener que escribirlo todo de cero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código desbloquea todos los entrys y elige cual debe desactivar usando un diccionario.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

v=Tk()
v.geometry("200x200")

def desactivador(Event=None):
    entrada1["state"]="normal"
    entrada2["state"]="normal"
    entrada3["state"]="normal"

    opciones[combobox.get()]["state"]="disable"

combobox = ttk.Combobox(v, state="readonly", values=("opcion1", "opcion2", "opcion3"))
combobox.current(0)
combobox.pack()

entrada1=ttk.Entry(v)
entrada1.pack()

entrada2=ttk.Entry(v)
entrada2.pack()

entrada3=ttk.Entry(v)
entrada3.pack()

#asocio cada opción con el entry que debe desactivar
opciones = {"opcion1":entrada1,
            "opcion2":entrada2,
            "opcion3":entrada3}

desactivador()


combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", desactivador)
v.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado!